# Separate date and time in R

Tags: r, datetime, time, datetime-format, lubridate

I have the dataset with the column consisting date and time as "character" class (the column "valid". I want to separate this column into two columns, one is for date and one is for time. But the values should be remained (not change).
This is the first 10 output from the data obtained from head(data, 10)

```
> head(data, 10)
   station            valid speed
1     PHNL 2021-01-01 00:00 14.95
2     PHNL 2021-01-01 00:05 21.85
3     PHNL 2021-01-01 00:10 17.25
4     PHNL 2021-01-01 00:15 19.55
5     PHNL 2021-01-01 00:20 16.10
6     PHNL 2021-01-01 00:25 17.25
7     PHNL 2021-01-01 00:30 12.65
8     PHNL 2021-01-01 00:35 17.25
9     PHNL 2021-01-01 00:40 18.40
10    PHNL 2021-01-01 00:45 17.25
```

I use as.POSIXct and I got the results as I expected for date, but the time column is just 00:00, it means the time is not updated as in the original column. How should I solve this problem? Kindly help and thank you in advance.

```
data$date=as.Date(data$valid) 
data$time=format(as.POSIXct(data$valid),
                 format="%H:%M")
```

Result

```
  station            valid speed       date  time
1    PHNL 2021-01-01 00:00 14.95 2021-01-01 00:00
2    PHNL 2021-01-01 00:05 21.85 2021-01-01 00:00
3    PHNL 2021-01-01 00:10 17.25 2021-01-01 00:00
4    PHNL 2021-01-01 00:15 19.55 2021-01-01 00:00
5    PHNL 2021-01-01 00:20 16.10 2021-01-01 00:00
6    PHNL 2021-01-01 00:25 17.25 2021-01-01 00:00
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. With your data in the specified format, I get the `time` column as expected - 00:00, 00:05, 00:10 etc

Comment: Don't have time to make a reprex right now. But consider
as.Date() like you have, and then subtract the original from the day (which is always 00:00). This difference is by definition the time, since it's always time since midnight!

Comment: @CarlosM. this will give you an integer number of seconds, so you are then left with the problem of converting that into HH:MM format. A better option might just be `data$time <- sub('^.+ (.*)$', '\\1', data$valid)`

Comment: regex works, I would personally just use integer seconds and convert only when needed so that math still applies (e.g., time1 > time2) which is how lubridate, zoo, etc. do comparisons anyway (treating as integers).

Comment: @Allan Cameron Actually this is intraday data, where we have 5-min observation for everyday, starting from 0AM and have observations till 23:55 each day, for the whole year of 2021. So I am thinking, maybe, the way the time is recorded in the original file is not "actual" time but the way of making 5-mins data starting from 0? If my guess is correct, how I can extract it with the same for "time" column?

Comment: @sehne I don't know if there's a problem with your data, because you haven't shared your data in reproducible format. Could you [edit] your question to include the output of `head(data, 10)`?

Comment: @AllanCameron It works now for me if I use this line code from you data$time <- sub('^.+ (.*)$', '\\1', data$valid). Thanks so much for that. But if you have time, could you explain, why does this code work in my case?

Comment: The function `sub` matches a part of your string using regular expressions and replaces it with something else. The part `^.+ ` means 'match characters up to and including the first space'. The part `(.*)$` means 'then match all the characters until the end of the string, and capture them. The replacement string of `\\1` means 'replace the matched characters with the first capture group'. Since all characters were matched, the entire string is replaced with the first capture group, which is everything after the first space. In your case, this is the HH:MM portion of your string.

Comment: A simpler alternative would be `sub('^.+ ', '', data$valid)`, which replaces everything up to and including the first space with empty characters, leaving only the time portion.

Comment: @AllanCameron Now I have just edited the questions with the head(data,10) and your previous approach of substract the character works, but now, I want it as saved as time in seperate column called "time", not characters, how should I do it? That is also my initial intention when using as.POSXct but as you can see it does not work for the time column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a couple of ways of doing it:

```
# load libraries
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, hms)

# create it as a tibble, so we can see the column types
read.table(text =
"    station            valid speed
1     PHNL '2021-01-01 00:00' 14.95
2     PHNL '2021-01-01 00:05' 21.85
3     PHNL '2021-01-01 00:10' 17.25
4     PHNL '2021-01-01 00:15' 19.55
5     PHNL '2021-01-01 00:20' 16.10
6     PHNL '2021-01-01 00:25' 17.25
7     PHNL '2021-01-01 00:30' 12.65
8     PHNL '2021-01-01 00:35' 17.25
9     PHNL '2021-01-01 00:40' 18.40
10    PHNL '2021-01-01 00:45' 17.25", header = TRUE) |> as_tibble() -> df

mutate(df, valid = as.POSIXct(valid, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),
           date = as.Date(valid), 
           time = format(valid, "%H:%M"))

# or
mutate(df, valid = as_datetime(valid, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),
              date = as_date(valid), 
              time = as_hms(format(valid, "%H:%M:%S")))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 5
   station valid               speed date       time  
   <chr>   <dttm>              <dbl> <date>     <time>
 1 PHNL    2021-01-01 00:00:00  15.0 2021-01-01 00'00"
 2 PHNL    2021-01-01 00:05:00  21.8 2021-01-01 05'00"
 3 PHNL    2021-01-01 00:10:00  17.2 2021-01-01 10'00"
 4 PHNL    2021-01-01 00:15:00  19.6 2021-01-01 15'00"
 5 PHNL    2021-01-01 00:20:00  16.1 2021-01-01 20'00"
 6 PHNL    2021-01-01 00:25:00  17.2 2021-01-01 25'00"
 7 PHNL    2021-01-01 00:30:00  12.6 2021-01-01 30'00"
 8 PHNL    2021-01-01 00:35:00  17.2 2021-01-01 35'00"
 9 PHNL    2021-01-01 00:40:00  18.4 2021-01-01 40'00"
10 PHNL    2021-01-01 00:45:00  17.2 2021-01-01 45'00"
```

Feel free to comment if you have any questions!